# How can I transfer variables from void methods?

Tags: java, variables, methods, void, transfer

I need to get latitude and longitude from: `public void onLocationChanged(Location location)` and transfer it to another method (JSON parser) so it can be applied to a url for weather API.  What's your guys suggestions for this?  I'm fairly new to this, a example would be really appreciated too.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&lon=" + location.getLongitude() + "&appid=5d8fea5f1c9cdfe8af473504e5f9002a";
    Log.i("api", url);

    //double lat = location.getLatitude();
   // double lng = location.getLongitude();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

What I need is the URL from the Location method to the JsonObjectRequest

```
private void jsonParse() {


        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject weatherData = response.getJSONObject("main");
                    double temp = weatherData.getDouble("temp");
                    double tempHigh = weatherData.getDouble("temp_max");
                    double tempLow = weatherData.getDouble("temp_min");
                    double humidity = weatherData.getDouble("humidity");


                    Log.i("JSONWork", String.valueOf(weatherData));
                    TV_temp_max.append("Highest Temperature: " + tempHigh);
                    TV_temp_min.append("Lowest Temperature: " + tempLow);
                    TV_temp.append("Current Temperature: " + temp);
                    TV_humidity.append("Humidity: %" + humidity);

                    JSONObject locationData = response.getJSONObject("sys");
                    String country = locationData.getString("country");
                    String city = locationData.getString("name");
                    TV_country.append(country);
                    TV_city.append(city);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i("error", "JSON is not working");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();


            }
        });

        mQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: Why must it be a void method?  That's an artificial constraint that makes no sense.

Comment: This depends on the architecture of your application. Send a message? Call a setter? Store it to some shared data store?

Comment: This person found this function event handler as part of an event handling api but has given no context and has no idea what he is doing

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it can only take void.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `onLocationChanged(Location location)` is called when the location has been updated to the one given as the parameter. So, if you want to process it further, just take it from there.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    String jsonLoc = createJson(loc);
    sendToWeatherApi(jsonLoc);
}
```